# How do I exclude certain beautifulsoup results that I don't want?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, hyperlink, python-requests, screen-scraping

I am having issues trying to exclude results given from my beautiful soup program this is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

URL = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Wikipedia_mobile_applications'
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))
```

I don't want to get the results that start with a "#" for example: #cite_ref-18

I have tried using for loops but I get this error message: `KeyError: 0`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `str.startswith()` method:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

URL = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Wikipedia_mobile_applications'
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

for tag in soup.find_all('a'):
    link = tag.get('href')
    if not str(link).startswith('#'):
        print(link)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS selector `a[href]:not([href^="#"])`. This will select all `<a>` tags with `href=` attribute but not the ones starting with `#` character:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Wikipedia_mobile_applications'
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

for link in soup.select('a[href]:not([href^="#"])'):
    print(link['href'])
```